# Opening/decrypting Webex Connect db3 file

Tags: database, sqlite, message, encryption, webex

So I have a lot of instant message logs/history that I want to back up from my chat client, Cisco WebEx Connect in Windows 7. These are stored under *C:\Users\\AppData\Local\WebEx Connect\Archive* and the file is called "myemailaddress".db3

After downloading SQLiteBrowser to open this file, I get the error:

> SQLiteManager: Error in opening file "myfile".db3 - either the file is encrypted or corrupt
>   Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED
>   Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED) [mozIStorageService.openUnsharedDatabase]

The file isn't corrupted so I'm thinking perhaps it is encrypted in some way - opening the file in Notepad displays random characters like the following, with no recognisable text:

> =¢^£ÍV¶»ñû‡«–
>   `×ÚµÏýº°ÎîÎL

Besides that file which contains the actual messages, there is another small 20kb file under the folder ConnectDB that has various config settings (such as create CacheTable) and it says on the first line (when opened in Notepad): "SQLite format 3" - so clearly this one isn't encrypted.

Is there any way to extract the data from the first file to something readable (ie, text)? It's only around 5MB in size so shouldn't be causing any memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't found a way for decrypting this file, however if you're still able to access the messenger client and have a live account you can still export them person by person by clicking on the person in question (make sure you've got view offline people enabled if you're retriving offline user's chat history) > click on the history tab > click on "save as".

I hope this is of use to you.